# Python timeout when making POST request from Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have deployed a Cloud Function to make a simple `POST` request when a file is uploaded to my storage bucket.

The function looks like this:

```
import requests

def hello_gcs(event, context):
    r = requests.post('http://192.168.2.198:8000/api/upload-data', data = {'file':event['name']})
```

Whenever I upload a file to the bucket I get a function finished with status: timeout. I found some similar questions on stack but nothing solve the problem. Does anyone see the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure ```http://192.168.2.198:8000``` is the right url?

Comment: @YashShah yes, everything works fine from postman

Comment: Does it work if you use `curl`?

Comment: @pepoluan curl works

Comment: is this the same machine that you have deployed the python code in or some other machine?

Comment: some other machine

Comment: is it in the same network? ```192.168.2.198``` suggests you should be in the same network. Try the same command from post man on the other machine. i think it will not work

Comment: @YashShah ohh I understand the problem now thats a lot yah you're right

Comment: Do you need more helps?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere no it's okay thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address `192.168.2.198` looks like an IP on a local network. This is probably not reachable from the Cloud Functions execution environment. You need to expose a public IP address instead.